# Ascii to binary calculation is flawed

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int BYTE = 8;
void print_bulb(int bit);

int main(void)
{
    string message = get_string("message: ");
    int v = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(message); i < len; i++)
    {
        int bits[BYTE];
        v = message[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            bits[j] = v % 2;
            printf("%i\n" , bits[j]);
        }
    } 
}

void print_bulb(int bit)
{
    if (bit == 0)
    {
        // Dark emoji
        printf("\U000026AB");
    }
    else if (bit == 1)
    {
        // Light emoji
        printf("\U0001F7E1");
    }
}
```

My initial idea was to mod the ascii values by 2 and store them in an array since mod only outputs 1s and 0s but I quickly realized that that doesn't work at all. The code outputs `000000011111111` for inputs `HI` which is not the expected `01001000 01001001`

Would there be a better approach to this problem using mod or is there something else I should be trying instead?

Comment: *"Would there be a better approach to this problem"* What problem? What are you trying to do? Are you aware that `'0'` is not equal to `0`?

Comment: please show input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use magic numbers. In `limits.h` you have a very handy macrodefinition called `CHAR_BIT`.
2. Do all arithmetic using `unsigned` numbers.
3. You do not need to call `strlen`.
4. You forgot to divide by two.
5. People better read binary numbers if they are displayed from the most significant bit.

```
int main(void)
{
    string message = get_string("message: ");
    int v = 0;
    while (*message)
    {
        int bits[CHAR_BIT];
        unsigned char v = *message++;
        for (int j = CHAR_BIT - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            bits[j] = !!(v & (1 << j));            
            printf("%i" , bits[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oan56czGb

Comment: @chqrlie pasted wrong version

Comment: suggest: `bits[j] = (v >> j) & 1;`

Answer (score 1):

To print the 8 bits in natural order, you must generate the bits from the most significant to the least significant and print a space between bytes:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *message = get_string("message: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char v = message[i];
        unsigned char mask;
        for (mask = 1u << (CHAR_BIT - 1); mask; mask >>= 1) {
            putchar((v & mask) ? '1' : '0');
        }
        putchar(message[i + 1] ? ' ' : '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 2.

```
bits[j] = v % 2;
v /= 2; // Add
```

Use unsigned type.

```
//int v = 0;
unsigned char v;
```

Reverse print order.

Or wait for [C24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)) and use `printf("%08hhb", message[i]);`

Comment: There's yet another issue: Bit order. This prints them from least significant to most.